# Shuffle Answers in Quiz in iPhone App

Tags: objective-c, shuffle

I've made a quiz and would like for it to shuffle the answers to make it more challenging.  This means that when there should be a method that can check which button is the answer. If answer is button 1 then button 1 contains the right answer. If answer is button 4 then button 4 contains the right answer etc.

Right now the code shuffles the answer each time I play a new game, but it sets the titles of all 4 buttons with the same title and the correct answer is always button 1.

Any ideas?

Philip

This is what I have.

```
- (IBAction)PlayHistory_Easy:(id)sender {

    // The questions        
    history_Easy = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:kHisQ_E1, kHisQ_E2, kHisQ_E3, kHisQ_E4,nil];

    numberOfQuestions = [history_Easy count];
    index = arc4random() % numberOfQuestions--;
    NSString *dd = [history_Easy objectAtIndex:index];
    questionLabel.text = dd;

    // Setup code to shuffle answers
    NSMutableArray *randomizeAnswer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree, btnFour, nil];
    NSMutableArray *ranAns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Answer 1", @"Answer 2", @"Answer 3", @"Answer 4", nil];

    if ([questionLabel.text isEqualToString:kHisQ_E1]) { // Answer 1st button

        for (UIButton *btn in randomizeAnswer) {

            int i = arc4random() % ranAns.count;
            NSString *str = [ranAns objectAtIndex:i];
            [btnOne setTitle:[ranAns objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnTwo setTitle:[ranAns objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnThree setTitle:[ranAns objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnFour setTitle:[ranAns objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

       } 
}
```

Check the answer. Here checking the answer is done manually, but in order to shuffle the answer, the code be different obviously.

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {

    if ([questionLabel.text isEqualToString:kHisQ_E1]) {
        [self playRIGHTAnswer_EASY];
    }
}

- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender {

    if ([questionLabel.text isEqualToString:kHisQ_E1]) {
        [self playWRONGAnswer_EASY];
    }
}

- (IBAction)button3:(id)sender {

    if ([questionLabel.text isEqualToString:kHisQ_E1]) {
        [self playWRONGAnswer_EASY];
    }
}

- (IBAction)button4:(id)sender {

    if ([questionLabel.text isEqualToString:kHisQ_E1]) {
        [self playWRONGAnswer_EASY];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all who is interested in this I provide an answer to my own question.

In trying to figure this out I thought that it would be easier to simply randomly reposition the buttons with each question. So I googled that and found this link:

[how to random placement of UIButton and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9714559/how-to-random-placement-of-uibutton-and-value)

I only used part of the code since I already had created my buttons in IB (with outlets and actions properly connected) and so only needed the code below. Whenever you call this code it replaces the buttons according to integer values you put in the mutable array.

```
- (void)randomlyPositionAnswerButtons {

    //Create an array with the rectangles used for the frames
    NSMutableArray *indexArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(28, 230, 260, 42)],
                                  [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(28, 296, 260, 42)],
                                  [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(28, 359, 260, 42)],
                                  [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(28, 422, 260, 42)], nil];

    //Randomize the array
    NSUInteger count = [indexArray count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        int nElements = count - i;
        int n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [indexArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }

    //Assign the frames
    btnOne.frame = [((NSValue *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:0]) CGRectValue];
    btnTwo.frame = [((NSValue *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:1]) CGRectValue];
    btnThree.frame = [((NSValue *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:2]) CGRectValue];
    btnFour.frame = [((NSValue *)[indexArray objectAtIndex:3]) CGRectValue];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have both logical errors and copy/paste errors.

Take a step back and separate your data store (the questions and answers) from the logic (the shuffling) and from the UI (the buttons). At the moment you're mixing all 3 of these things together and it's really messy.

Your data should be stored so that you have a list of items containing:

1. Question
2. Possible answers
3. Correct answer

When you shuffle, just change the orders of the possible answers (maybe in a mutable copy of the source list). There are many algorithms for shuffling, but when you iterate over the list you should generally be swapping two items each time.

Now, taking your shuffled answers you can set the value of each button. This should be trivial. Don't think about shuffling buttons...

When a button is pressed, get the answer associated with it and compare it to the correct answer. Done.

If you want to shuffle the questions as a whole, that should be done as a single stage before any of the above is started.